# Move superview when moving subview - ObjectiveC

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiview

I have a super`UIView` which has a sub`UIView`. The sub`UIView` has the `UIPanGestureRecognizer`.

I need to move the super`UIView` when the user tries to move the `subUIView`.

I do not want to set the center as that would give a jerk.

I need to move the super`UIView` smoothly when the user tries to move the sub`UIView`.Because the super`UIView` is moving, the user will get the feeling that he is moving the sub`UIView`.

So, I how do I get this done?

Answer (score 1):

You can set the center to avoid jerk use `UIView` animation block

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5
                         animations:^{
                            //set center here
                         }
                         completion:^(BOOL finished) {

                         }];
```

Answer (score 0):

assuming you set the frame of the `subUIView` when the gesture recognizer triggers, just move the super view the same amount

```
subview.frame = CGRectMake(-x,-y,w,h); //move opposite way to superview
[subview superview].frame = CGRectMake(x,y,w,h); //move
```

edit: misinterpreted what you were trying to accomplish a bit, you would need to move the subview the opposite way to which the superview is moving for the subview to stay in place while the superview moves